# Mapping unit circle with the map $\omega= \frac{z\ln z}{z^{2}+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, multivalued-functions

In an exercise involving conformal mappings, the task is to determine the line in the $\omega$ plane traced by the point $\omega= \frac{z\ln z}{z^{2}+1}$, as $z$ traces the unit circle. I am not sure whether this is a trick question because I feel like I need to deform the given contour to a dogbone contour as $arg\left ( z \right ) \in\left [-\pi,\pi  \right )$

Comment: $\ln$ is not normally defined on $\mathbb{C}$. Do you mean $\log{z}$, or $\ln|z|$?

Comment: @Chappers I mean I know that $\ln \left(z\right)$ is a multivalued function, and that's what confused me. We cannot cross the negative real axis without adding $2\pi i$